# How to install Sharepoint 2010 using VMs?

Tags: installation

I have 3 VMs. I want to know how can i install sharepoint using these 3 VMs.
1) SP2010Client
2) SP2010-WIN2008
3) SQL2008-WIN2008
4) password.txt

Comment: Have you read any TechNet documentation? What is it you're stuck with? Check this for starters: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee667264(office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Im a bit confused at what your trying to do? are the three vm all the same and you want to install sharepoint 2010 on all of them?

if yes then check this out:

http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/sharepoint-2010-virtual-machine-vm-installing-sharepoint-2010-44/

Copy the vhd to other 2 :)

if no that means you want to know how to install all three options you posted on individual virtual machines:

1)SP2010Client

http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/sharepoint-2010-virtual-machine-vm-installing-sharepoint-2010-44/

2)SP2010-WIN2008

http://mosshowto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/installing-sharepoint-2010-windows-2008.html

3)SQL2008-WIN2008

http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2011/04/01/how-to-install-sql-2008-r2-on-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-for-use-with-scvmm-2008-r2-sp1.aspx

hope it answers your question!